# What is the pronunciation difference between ち and ぢ

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

While several people have asked about the pronunciation difference between じ and ぢ(there is none), the difference between ち and ぢ has not been talked about much. Yet, they seem the same to me, even though their Romaji is different. The pronunciation of ち is like the English letter 'j' (as in judge) and so is the pronunciation for ぢ.

I am confused about the pronunciation difference between 'chi' and 'ji'.

Comment: What's your native language?

Comment: German (Swiss German)

Comment: In what word does ち sound like "g" to you?

Comment: I meant the ‚g‘ as in age, not as in ‚gangster‘. I tried to make it more clear.

Comment: @aguijonazo German has final devoicing — that might be why ち sounds like the final in "age" as pronounced in that English variety.

Comment: I know you meant the “soft” G. But does ち always sound like that, or depending on its position in the word?

Comment: @aguijonazo You mean if it sounds differently TO ME depending on the position? I don't know, I am a beginner and haven't had much exposure yet to have noticed any difference. Do sounds in Japanese change depending on their position?

Comment: To make one thing clear, in the English language, the sounds 'j' as in 'judje', 'ch' as in 'chicken' and 'g' as in 'age' all sound the same to me. As has been pointed out in the comments below, this is not true and thus I can't hear the difference between 'chi' and 'ji' either. What I understand is that 'chi' is not voiced while 'ji' is. When I learned English I made the same mistake with 's' and 'z'. In German the 'z' is pronounced like 'ts' as in 'nuts', however in English the 'z' is a voiced 's'. Since there is no voiced 's' in German I always pronounced it like an unvoiced 's'.

Comment: The consonant doesn't change much except it might get slightly stronger aspiration at the beginning of a word but the vowel /i/ may get devoiced before another voiceless consonant or at the end of a word. I thought you might be hearing it as じ only in other positions than those.

Answer (score 1):

The pronounciation of ち is not like "g", but rather it is similar to the "chi" in "chicken", like the romaji notation suggests. The difference is that it is voiceless (and always pronounced as an affricate). The dakuten ゛ turns voiceless consonants into voiced consonants.

Comment: Yes indeed, but isn't the pronunciation of ぢ like 'chi' as in chicken as well? Also the 'chi' in chicken is not voiceless, no? A voiceless version of 'chi' would be 'shi'

Comment: @timtam No, the first sound in chicken is indeed voiceless, and it's the affricate /tʃ/ 'tsh'. Its relation to /ʃ/ 'sh' is that you get it if you remove the plosive part. The voiced counterpart is /dʒ/ 'j' like the first sound in 'judge', made up of a d plosive sound and a /ʒ/ like a French soft G. However, Swiss German lacks either sound, right? Thus the distinction may be hard to hear.

Comment: Mm… yeah in Swiss German we have ‚tsch‘, which might be similair. But I actually can‘t hear the difference in the first sound in ‚judge‘ and ‚chicken‘ :(

Comment: ち is pronounced like the sound in "cheek", "cheese", or "cheap".  It's nothing like the "chi" in "chicken".  And if you're pronouncing "chicken" like "chee-cken", you're pronouncing it wrong.

Comment: @istrasci isn't what you're referring to the pronunciation of the vowels after 'ch'? Of course I do not say "chee-cken" but my question is about the pronunciation of the sound 'ch' not what comes after it

Comment: @timtam - If you have difficulty telling “jeez” from “cheese” in English, you might indeed have a harder time with ち and じ in Japanese because the consonant in ち is generally much weaker than the English “ch”. You need to get used to the sounds through more exposure, I would say.

Comment: @aguijonazo yes that's it. I always thought 'jeez' and 'cheese' would be pronounced the same, but apparently that's not the case. At least now I am know what I have to work on. Thanks!